# How to get the name of the role from the Controller to the Custom AuthorizeAttribute class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am developing MVC application and using ASP.NET identity for User Roles. I have override 3 functions of AuthorizeAttribute class as:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private readonly string[] allowedroles;        
        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
        { this.allowedroles = roles; }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            string usr = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var userId = context.Users.Where(item => item.UserName == usr).Single().Id;
            var uroles = context.Roles.ToList();
            bool authorize = false;
            foreach (var role in uroles)
            {
                var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id)).ToList();
                if (user.Count() > 0)
                { authorize = true; }
            }
            return authorize;
        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        { filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("Access is Denied!"); }
    }
```

Now my controller Authorization is as:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Delete COA")]
```

And my code authorize the current user for it even then when in the dbo.AspNetRoles tables I have no role assigned to the current user with the name "Delete COA". But since my CustomeAuthorizeAttribute Class is not getting the name of the role attribute from the controller I am unable to filter as per the roles of the current User.

Instead the constructor code

```
this.allowedroles = roles;
```

gets the string as:

```
roles = {string[0]}
```

but I need the name of the role here. What is wrong here?

Comment: your looking for  `this.allowedroles = Roles;` why are you retrieving all the users in a specific role, to authorize one user, it doesn't make sense

Comment: Suppose I have a user who has 3 different roles and other one with a single role. So when the second user tries to access the other 2 roles (not assigned to him) then the access should be denied to him. How could I be able to deny or allow that if I won't get the name of the role from the controller. What should I do??

Comment: i am a newbie to asp.net identity so plz guide me hoe to implement it.. @3dd

Comment: bcoz the method only checks that if the current user has any given role or not.. It doesnot check that which role is given to the user and which is not

Comment: If there are more than one role in the attribute they are usually specified with a `,` seperator, so you can use `var roles = Rols.split(',')` then use contains on the array to find if the user can access the resource

Comment: @3dd, THANK you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using property as a parameter. Since `AuthorizeAttribute` already have had `Role` property you could simply use it.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext(); 

    // you don't need the constrictor and private roles field  

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // spiting different roles by ',' 
        var roles=this.Rols.Split(',');
        // rest of your code
    }
}
```

And you could apply to any action then:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Delete COA")]
public ActionResoult MyFancyAction(){}
```

Or for multiple role you could:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles="FirstRole,SecondRole,AndSoOn")]
public ActionResoult MyFancyAction(){}
```